# How to efficiently transfer values in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to ask if there is a more efficient way to transfer values within a dataframe than entering all the cell locations one-by-one.

Suppose there is a set of cells (120, 50:100) with certain inputs, while there is another set of empty cells (0:50, 110). Both sets of cells have a size of 50 * 1 (50 cells in total), but with different numbers of columns and rows.

In this situation, there are two transformations that I would like to carry out:

1st transformation:
Transfer the inputs in cells (120, 50:100) to cells (0:50, 110), such that cell (0, 110) = cell (120, 50), cell (1, 110) = cell (120, 51), ..., cell (49, 110) = cell (120, 99).

2nd transformation:
Transfer the inputs in cells (120, 50:100) to cells (0:50, 110), such that cell (0, 110) = cell (120, 99), cell (1, 110) = cell (120, 98), ..., cell (49, 110) = cell (120, 50)

Apart from directly assigning the required values via the command `df.iloc[a, b] = df.iloc[c, d]` for 50 times in each transformation, is there a more efficient way to carry out the transformation above. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `.iloc` takes slices... so you're probably after: `df.iloc[:50, 110] = df.iloc[120, 50:100]` ?

Comment: I have tried before but it does not work, as it returns NaN for all values in cells (0:50, 110).

Comment: Could you add what you tried in a small reproducible sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing using `iloc`, i.e. `df.iloc[:50, 110] = df.iloc[120, 50:100]` is likely to not work because `iloc` in this case returns a `Series` and the `Series` remember the indexes (column names in this case). The assignmen operator `=` in ths case always replace elements of the same index. So since the indexes of the two series are different (`df.iloc[:50, 110]` has row names or indexes as indexes, `df.iloc[120, 50:100]` has column names or indexes as indexes) the substitution goes wrong.

You can see this if you print `df.iloc[:50, 110].index` and `df.iloc[120, 50:100].index`. The substitution is done only where those indexes matches, which is not likely your case.

To achieve what you want, you can use the underliying `numpy` array, which does not enforce any check on indexes.

```
df.values[:50, 110] = df.values[120, 50:100]
```

and for reversing the order of the assignment:

```
df.values[:50, 110] = df.values[120, 50:100:-1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I encountered the following problem after modifying my codes: "could not broadcast input array from shape (0) into shape (50)".

Comment: That means that the size of the selected arrays is not the same. You cannot copy a shorter array into a longer or viceversa. Be sure that the length is the same. `shape(0)` in particular means that you have an empty selection somewhere.